# How to start WSL in windows terminal programmatically and run command

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I would like to start Ubuntu WSL [shell: `bash`] inside Windows Terminal from a batch file and pass a command, which should immediately run after startup.

- When directly starting WSL, I'm able to do this using the `-c` argument; e.g. the following opens WSL and establishes an SSH connection with some local port forwardings:

  ```bsh
  bash -c "ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -L 5900:localhost:5900 -L 8001:localhost:8001 user@target.com"
  ```

How would I achieve this using Windows Terminal?

Comment: Which shell are you using in Windows Terminal and what error are you getting when running the above command?

Comment: @suamikim - You should edit your question instead of replying with a temporary comment

Comment: Windows Terminal is still in a beta stage and it's not possible to do what you want because it still lacks broad functionality; however, [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) can. Another option is to use Task Scheduler since WSL's terminal has been hardcoded into Windows [it's available via the context menu, so it can likely be launched via Powershell].

Comment: @JW0914 Could you give a little more detail about how I could use the Task Scheduler to go about this?

Comment: @suamikim I can't provide a complete answer since I'm not proficient in Powershell, however it should be possible to launch a WSL terminal via a Powershell script, either having the command issued from the Powershell script or in a separate Bash script in WSL. In Task Scheduler, you'd configure the script to run at either Startup or Login. Out of curiosity, have you considered executing from WSL's [`/etc/rc.local`](https://askubuntu.com/q/9853/828054) script, [`crontab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), etc., of which bypasses the Windows side of it altogether?

Comment: @JW0914 Launching `wt` from batch/PowerShell/... is not the issue here but handing it a cmd to execute after startup is. Also I don't want to run my batch file on a scheduled basis but execute it manually, so I don't think the Task Scheduler will help me in any way. Using `rc.local` or `crontab` also don't really help me here since I don't want to run my cmd EVERYTIME I start the WSL bash but only when started from my batch file... Thanks for your input!

Comment: @suamikim I wasn't talking about launching `wt` from a script, as `wt` lacks basic terminal emulation functionality (it's still a beta). **What I was talking about** is issuing the WSL Bash terminal command directly via a Powershell script and is likely the only way to natively do what you want to do. As I previously mentioned, you can do exactly what you're trying to do via ConEmu by adding a Task [a terminal profile] in Settings → Startup → Tasks _(you can also specify variables in Settings → Startup → Environment)_. ConEmu should auto-add the WSL terminal during install/first launch.

Comment: @JW0914 Ok, then I still don't get what you really have in mind. What exactly do you mean by "issuing the WSL Bash terminal command directly via a Powershell script"? Using PowerShell, I'd still have to know how to pass the correct params to the `wt` start cmd? So I don't really see how PowerShell gives me more "power" here then a regular bash script? Regarding `ConEmu`: Thanks for the tip, however I'm not looking for an alternative to `wt` ATM.

Comment: @suamikim `wt` is a _Terminal Emulator_, not a **terminal**... the _terminal_ is Bash. To make this simpler, simply install ConEmu and you can issue the command as written in your question. _(Since WSL'S Bash terminal is now hardcoded into Windows 10 [it's available in the Context Menu], it should be able to be called from a Powershell script, but to keep this simple, simply use ConEmu instead of Windows Terminal, at the very least until it's finalized software with the full functionality of a terminal emulator.)_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found two ways, with both working so far:

1. **Create a dedicated profile:** 
    The `commandline` option also accepts arguments, which are directly passed to the shell on startup, allowing the direct usage of `wsl.exe` with an additional "startup command":

   ```js
   {
     "guid": "{...}",
     "hidden": false,
     "name": "Ubuntu SSH",
     "commandline": "wsl.exe ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -L 5900:localhost:5900 -L 8001:localhost:8001 user@target.com",
   }
   ```

   I can now start the shell via a batch file, which runs using the below; however, the downside is the new profile is shown in Windows Terminal's *Profile Selection Menu*:

   ```bsh
   wt -p "Ubuntu SSH"
   ```
2. **Pass `commandline` to `wt`:** 
    As shown in Option 1, the `commandline` option can include further parameters for the target shell, with the following working when called from a batch file:

   ```bsh
   wt wsl.exe ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -L 5900:localhost:5900 -L 8001:localhost:8001 user@target.com
   ```

   I did not find any official online resources explaining why this works, adjusting the suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832189/1273551), so I'm not sure whether this is supposed to work this way or if it's a hidden/unintentional feature that could break in future versions.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, terminal emulators are supposed to be able to function like that, `wt` simply lacks the full functionality of basic terminal emulation because it's still beta software _(if VS Code is any indication, once `wt` becomes RTM as finalized software, it will likely be just as configurable and functional as ConEmu, one of the most feature-rich and customizable terminal emulators for Windows)_

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the additional info! However, could you please stop promoting `ConEmu` so hard? Whilst I'm pretty sure it's very good software, it has very little to do with my initial question & mentioning it over & over again is therefore simply besides the topic here...

Comment: It's not about promoting ConEmu, it's the fact ConEmu works where Windows Terminal does not because, as I've repeatedly stated, Windows Terminal is **_Beta_** software, lacking even the most basic terminal emulation functionality. You asked how to execute your command and ConEmu does so w/o any workaround simply by calling the default task [Bash] that is auto-added during install to run the command within that terminal _(Bash task output: `set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -cur_console:pm:/mnt`)_. Either way, I'm done talking in circles.

Comment: I understood your argument about `ConEmu` & `WT` being beta right from the beginning and appreciate you showing up the alternative. However, my question was always "how to execute the command **using WT**"...

Comment: `wt` without `-p` flag runs default profile (which is _Windows Powershell_ initially)… Also note that Microsoft retired _Bash on Ubuntu on Windows_ once they introduced multiple WSL distributions. Run `wsl.exe [command]` instead of `bash.exe [-c "command"]` .

Comment: Check [Using command-line arguments for Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832189/3439404) as well.

Comment: @JosefZ Using `wsl.exe "command"` instead of `bash.exe -c "command"` gives me this error: `/bin/bash: ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 -L 5900:localhost:5900 -L 8001:localhost:8001 user@target.com: command not found`

Comment: Oh yes, I know… That's why I gave both examples `bash.exe [-c "command"]` versus `wsl.exe [command]` (note the presence/absence of double quotes).

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for the additional info! Without the quotes, the command runs as described!

Comment: Do you know why this command gives error? `wt -p "Ubuntu18" phpstorm.sh` I just want to start a script that I have globally once WSL is opened, it opens but does not execute `phpstorm.sh`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct : Windows Terminal does not have a `-c` parameter.

The [syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows) is:

```
wt [options] [command ; ]
```

Where the only options are:

```
  -h,--help                   Print this help message and exit
  -v,--version                Display the application version
  -M,--maximized Excludes: --fullscreen
                              Launch the window maximized
  -F,--fullscreen Excludes: --maximized
                              Launch the window in fullscreen mode
  -p                          Profile
  -d                          Directory
```